# How to compare minutes in 2 dates in Phoenix/Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to find a time difference in minutes between "utc now" and a variable of type `Ecto.DateTime`. What's the easiest way to do that? Should I convert both of them in unix time and subtract instead of doing pattern matching and comparing year, month, day and hour first and only after that actually subtracting minutes? I'm not looking to using any third-party dependencies.

Comment: Do you mean `now()` from SQL?

Comment: By "utc now" you mean the new `DateTime.utc_now/0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIC: [`Ecto.DateTime` is a struct](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.1.3/lib/ecto/date_time.ex#L404) and it has a [`Ecto.DateTime.from_erl/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#from_erl/1) helper (as well as `from_unix!` and some others.) It also is responsible for generating “utc now” with [`Ecto.DateTime.utc/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#utc/1).

Elixir `DateTime` has in turn [`to_unix/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#to_unix/2), hence one might:

```
dt1, dt2 = [ecto_time, Ecto.DateTime.utc]
           |> Enum.map(&Ecto.DateTime.to_erl/1)
           |> Enum.map(&NaiveDateTime.from_erl!/1)
           |> Enum.map(&DateTime.from_naive!(&1, "Etc/UTC"))
           |> Enum.map(&DateTime.to_unix(&1))
mins = (dt1 - dt2) / 60
```

Comment: (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in DateTime.to_unix/2

Comment: Oh, indeed, `DateTime.to_unix/2` expects the `DateTime`, not `Ecto.DateTime`. Will update in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `Ecto.DateTime` to `DateTime` with UTC Timezone and then compare their `to_unix`:

```
iex(1)> now = DateTime.utc_now |> DateTime.to_unix
1486544161
iex(2)> now2 = Ecto.DateTime.utc |> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl |> NaiveDateTime.from_erl! |> DateTime.from_naive!("Etc/UTC") |> DateTime.to_unix
1486544206
iex(3)> (now2 - now) / 60
0.75
```

Pattern matching would not be a good idea as you'll have to handle every case of the year/month/day/hour/minute/second overflowing after adding/subtracting.

Answer (score -1):

Elixir has a [`DateTime.diff/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#diff/3) method now.

```
DateTime.diff(dt1, dt2, :minute)
```

(In your case dtx is `DateTime.utc_now`)